# How to install android studio on usb drive without administrator

Tags: java, android, batch-file, path, android-studio

I have installed both a jdk and android studio on a usb drive, however android studio doesn't seem to want to launch from that jdk (it instead says none are installed), I have looked online and these solutions have been suggested:
    - Adding the JDK to my system path file, as I want to run this on a school computer that wont be possible, as you need admin
    - Changing the settings inside of android studio, given that i cant even get it to launch this is not an option
    - I have tried to add something to the studio.bat, but I probably got it wrong, and it didn't work.

I think the most promising option is to add it to studio.bat, would any of you know how to do this (the jdk is located in the same drive but in/jdk no/AndroidStudio)?

I would be open to other options that don't require admin permission.

I have poked around and I think this would be a solution but i can't work out how:

I need to add E:\JDK7 as my JAVA_HOME to this file (studio.bat):

```
IF EXIST "%ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK%" SET JDK=%ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK%
IF NOT "%JDK%" == "" GOTO jdk
IF EXIST "%~dp0\..\jre" SET JDK=%~dp0\..\jre
IF NOT "%JDK%" == "" GOTO jdk
IF EXIST "%JDK_HOME%" SET JDK=%JDK_HOME%
IF NOT "%JDK%" == "" GOTO jdk
IF EXIST "%JAVA_HOME%" SET JDK=%JAVA_HOME%
IF "%JDK%" == "" GOTO error

:jdk
SET JAVA_EXE=%JDK%\bin\java.exe
IF NOT EXIST "%JAVA_EXE%" SET JAVA_EXE=%JDK%\jre\bin\java.exe
IF NOT EXIST "%JAVA_EXE%" GOTO error

SET JRE=%JDK%
IF EXIST "%JRE%\jre" SET JRE=%JDK%\jre
SET BITS=
IF EXIST "%JRE%\lib\amd64" SET BITS=64
```

I have tried adding this to the file (below IF EXIST "%JAVA_HOME):

```
IF NOT "%JDK%" == "" GOTO jdk
IF EXIST "E:\JDK7" SET JDK=E:\JDK7
```

Comment: The PATH variable exists in a system wide and user wide variant. For changing the latter you don't need admin permissions. Also you can set the PATH in a batch file for that batch file.

Comment: I tried to use a batch file based on online tutorials, but it didn't work, could you tell me what I need to but in the batch file? Also I think my school admins block .bat and cmd, I want a way to set some form of permanent static link in android studio (the jdk file isn't moving)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batch file work for me. I have jdk installed on a  usb stick at the location \Java\jdk1.7.0_75 and a studio.bat file with:

```
set Path=\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin;%Path%
set JDK_HOME=%JDK%\java\jdk1.7.0_75
set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA%\java\jdk1.7.0_75
\AndroidStudio\bin\studio
```

Comment: Yeah, I have since given up on the idea (couldn't install USB drivers)

Answer (score 0):

1) Extract tools.zip from downloaded JDK, then run
`for /R %f in (.\*.pack) do @"/path/to/tools.zip/bin/unpack200" -r -v -l "" "%f" "%~pf%~nf.jar"`

2) Move the extracted folder under Android Studio, then rename it to "jre".

3) Profit.

---

> FYI how the folder tree likes:
>   `~/AndroidStudio/
>                  bin/
>                  lib/
>                  ...
>                  jre/`